# ACRCloud webapi in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newb hobbyist developer.  Can I just throw [this repo](https://github.com/acrcloud/webapi_example/blob/master/identify%20protocol%201%20(recommended)/IdentifyProtocolV1.rb) of their ACRCloud's ruby example code into a controller?   I'd like to use an audio fingerprinting song recognition database as a name validation for songs users are uploading using paperclip.   Not sure if it's possible, just starting to research it, any hints or suggestions would be appreciated.

Obviously I'd have to replace

```
file_name = ARGV[0]
```

etc, but I'm also wondering about the require 'openssl' etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely! But there are few points to be taken care of. That's a pure ruby script, when it comes to rails there are certain rules/best practices. One of which is thin controller and fat model..

1. You need to create a route/action in your app which will ask the app to execute this request with required params.
2. Write a method in your model which contains the code and call it from controller and pass the permitted params to it.
3. Instead of hardcoding your credentials in the model, make them environment variables.
4. Would suggest using [Httparty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) wgich will reduce many lines of your code and you just need to pass headers, params, etc. as hash in the arguments.
5. Last, but not the least...if you notice..there's a puts in the end however, rails uses mvc and so you need to have a view for the controller action you created in step1. Return and save the response.body in the class variable like `@response = res.body` and you can play with the body depending on the response type.
   Hope it helps..

P.S. I wish I could write few lines of code/optimise it for you but i m using my mobile right now. But I think this much information should be enough to convert that script to mvc rails structure..

Comment: right on man, thanks a lot.  if you were to see my code you would literally puke, but i'm a musician and i've only got one site to build.  i'll get started, and if you ever get a chance to extend on this it would be much appreciated.  thanks!